# video conferencing in java using JMF/RTP

Tags: java, jmf, video-conferencing

I need to implement Video conferencing in intranet using JMF API.But i dint know where to start with ? I have knowledge of JMF but how to implement this thing that i need to know.
I need to know how RTP sessions are created and used while the video streaming is done?

Answer (score 0):

Use Jitsi, they have about the best library I've found for RTP streaming. Note that they use FMJ in-place of JMF.

Their site: https://jitsi.org/

Their code: https://github.com/jitsi

Check out libjitsi if you just want the libraries.